# How to log all error ocured in site?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, logging

I want write an module how log all errors in site. Please guide me.

Comment: The answers won't log all errors - rather the unhandled exceptions

Answer (score 2):

Global.asax:

```
 <%@ Application Inherits="MyProj.Global" %>
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
namespace MyProj
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        protected virtual void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Application_Error event, that can be put in a Global.asax file (more info [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ErrorHandlingASPNET.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.error.aspx)).
Basically that event is called every time there is an unhandled exception in your application code - one more reason not to handle exceptions that you can't manage.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write your own but use an existing one like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Suggest looking at the little-known free [ELMAH error reporting module](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) for ASP.NET.

Very cool:

[image: ELMAH in action]